# Activate textbox on change of an item in Drop down in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to do the following:

I have drop down menu with four options in it. When I choose Shipped a text box should enabled. So I tried the following:

```
<div class="col-md-3"> 
    <select class="form-control" id="ostatus" name= "ostatus">      
        <option value="Uploaded" <?php if ($dispatch_status == "Uploaded") echo "selected='selected'";?> >Uploaded</option>
        <option value="Processing" <?php if ($dispatch_status == "Processing") echo "selected='selected'";?> >Processing</option>
        <option value="Dispatched" <?php if ($dispatch_status == "Dispatched") echo "selected='selected'";?> >Dispatched</option>
        <option value="Shipped" <?php if ($dispatch_status == "Shipped") echo "selected='selected'";?> >Shipped</option>                                                                                
    </select>
</div>                                    
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_notes"  disabled="true" id="shipping_notes" aria-describedby="" placeholder="Enter Shipping details">
```

Java script:

```
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('ostatus').addEventListener('change', function() 
    {
        console.log(this.value);

        if (this.value == 'Shipped') {
            document.getElementById('shipping_notes').disabled = false;   
        } else {
            document.getElementById('shipping_notes').disabled = true;
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
```

Doesn't seem to trigger? I don't see log on console too. What could be wrong here?

**Update:**

I have pasted the html code here:

https://justpaste.it/6zxwu

Comment: You cannot add event listener to element not even created yet by putting js in <head> tag. Try moving this code at then end before </body> tag and within <script> tags

Comment: I have something called footer.php that I have included in the end. I have put the code in that PHP file. It is the same. What are the other solution?

Comment: Your browser JavaScript setting might be disabled. Try document.write somewhere in the middle of html within script tags of course and if that didn't show, enable JS in browser otherwise try to use a library like jquery and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Since you've now shared your other code I think I know what you want.  You have multiple modals, each with a `select` list and `shipping_notes` textbox which should be enabled when the selection is `Shipped` for that particular modal. I've modified your HTML to get this working.

I've updated your HTML a bit. You have multiple elements with the same ID.  HTML IDs should be unique.  If you want to target multiple elements it's safer to use `class` (or `data-`) attributes. I've added `class="order-status"` to each `select` and `class="shipping_notes_txt"` to each textbox.  I've used [`element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select DOM elements.

The snippet below mimics two modals. When the `select` is updated, it only enables/disabled the textbox within the same `form` element.

```js
// wait for the DOM to load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // get all select elements with class=order-status
  var selects = document.querySelectorAll('.order-status');

  // iterate over all select elements
  for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    // current element
    var element = selects[i];

    // add event listener to element
    element.addEventListener('change', function() 
    {
      console.log(this.value); 

      // get the form closest to this element
      var form = this.closest('form');

      // find the shipping notes textbox inside form and disable/enable
      if (this.value == 'Shipped') {
        form.querySelector('.shipping_notes_txt').disabled = false;   
      } else {
        form.querySelector('.shipping_notes_txt').disabled = true;
      }
    });

    // default value if status == Shipped: enable textbox
    if (element.value == "Shipped")
    {
      var form = element.closest('form');
      form.querySelector('.shipping_notes_txt').disabled = false;
    }
  }  
});
```

```css
.modal1 { 
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top; 
  padding: .5em;
  padding-bottom:5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal1">  
  <h3>First Modal</h3>
  <div id="edit1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <form action="order.php" autocomplete="off" method="post">
      <div class="col-md-2 ml-3 pt-1">
        <label for="role" class="mr-3">Status</label>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control order-status" id="ostatus1" name= "ostatus">
        <option value="Uploaded" selected='selected' >Uploaded</option>
        <option value="Processing">Processing</option>
        <option value="Dispatched">Dispatched</option>
        <option value="Shipped">Shipped</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="form-control shipping_notes_txt" name="shipping_notes" disabled="true" id="shipping_notes1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Shipping details">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="modal1">    
  <h3>Second Modal</h3>
  <div id="edit20" class="modal fade" role="dialog" >
    <form action="order.php" autocomplete="off" method="post">
      <div class="col-md-2 ml-3 pt-1">
        <label for="role" class="mr-3">Status</label>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control order-status" id="ostatus20" name= "ostatus">
        <option value="Uploaded" >Uploaded</option>
        <option value="Processing">Processing</option>
        <option value="Dispatched">Dispatched</option>
        <option value="Shipped" selected='selected' >Shipped</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="form-control shipping_notes_txt" name="shipping_notes" disabled="true" id="shipping_notes20" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Shipping details">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The console is not printing anything :( Not sure what is wrong?

Comment: Only the first time on refresh I am getting the option after that I don't see it.

Comment: I have simple dialog modal opened and I have the above code. I am not able to get it because it is opening inside a modal? I thought that way and used the same inside my PHP directly without a dialog modal and still, I have an issue.

Comment: What I was trying to say was I refreshed the page it worked once and then I tried the code again it didn't work.

Comment: Let me explain what I have: I have a table with data getting from DB. inside the while loop, I have edit too. When I click the edit a modal dialog is opened with the above drop down and textbox. This is inside the form, I also have a save button. So I enter the details and click save which closes the dialog box and reloads the page and data is saved to db.

Comment: BTW: I just realized the disable and enable works only in the first row in the table and not others.

Comment: @SanjanaNair I have updated my answer with what you want (I think). This should work for multiple modals.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay! Yes. This worked. I did some modification and it worked for my requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add onchange to your `<select>`

```
<select class="form-control" id="ostatus" name= "ostatus" onchange = "statuschange()">
```

And change the JavaScript to :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function statuschange(){
  var drpDownValue = document.getElementById('ostatus').value;
  if (drpDownValue == 'Shipped') 
  {
      document.getElementById('shipping_notes').disabled = false;   
  } 
  else 
  {
      document.getElementById('shipping_notes').disabled = true;
  }      
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: Then I think it has something to do with your php code, did you try developer tools to see if that function is called or not on change of the dropdown box ?

Comment: How do I do that? Can you please guide me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

assuming everything on the server side this works HTML comes first

```html
<div class="col-md-3">                                                                              <select class="form-control" id="ostatus" name= "ostatus">                                                                          
            <option value="Uploaded" selected="selected" >Uploaded</option>
            <option value="Processing" >Processing</option>
            <option value="Dispatched" >Dispatched</option>
            <option value="Shipped" >Shipped</option>                                                                                
        </select>
    </div>                                    
</div>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_notes"  disabled="true" id="shipping_notes" aria-describedby="" placeholder="Enter Shipping details">
```

```
document.getElementById('ostatus').addEventListener('change', function() 
{
    console.log(this.value);

    if (this.value == 'Shipped') {
        document.getElementById('shipping_notes').disabled = false;   
    } else {
        document.getElementById('shipping_notes').disabled = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: still the Same issue.